# JavaFX - TextField with regex for zipcode

Tags: regex, javafx, textfield, zipcode

for my programm I want to use a TextField where the user can enter a zipcode (German ones). For that I tried what you can see below. If the user enters more than 5 digits every additional digit shall be deleted immediately. Of course letters are not allowed.

When I use this pattern ^[0-9]{0,5}$ on https://regex101.com/ it does what I intended to, but when I try this in JavaFX it doesn't work. But I couldn't find a solution yet.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Edit: For people, who didn't work with JavaFX yet: When the user enters just one character, the method check(String text) is called. So the result should also be true, when there are 1 to 5 digits. But not more ;-)

```java
public class NumberTextField extends TextField{

    ErrorLabel label;

    NumberTextField(String text, ErrorLabel label){
        setText(text);
        setFont(Font.font("Calibri", 17));
        setMinHeight(35);
        setMinWidth(200);
        setMaxWidth(200);
        this.label = label;
    }

    NumberTextField(){}

    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text){
        if(check(text)) {
            super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text){
        if(check(text)){
            super.replaceSelection(text);
        }
    }

    private boolean check(String text){
        if(text.matches("^[0-9]{0,5}$")){
            label.setText("Success");
            label.setBlack();
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the `^` and `$`, because with `.matches()`, the **full** string has to match the pattern already. Anyway, it should work. `"12345".matches("^[0-9]{0,5}$")` gives me `true`.

Comment: How do you tell Java the field is only digits ? How do you tell Java the field length is only 5 ? You could just replace the field every time with this regex find `^\D*([0-9]{0,5})[\S\s]*` replace `$1`

Comment: @mumpitz you're right, but when I put in more numbers in the textfield, it doesn't remove additional digits. Only letters are removed right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extend `TextField` to do this. In fact I recommend using a `TextFormatter`, since this is simpler to implement:
It does not require you to overwrite multiple method. You simply need to decide based on the data about the desired input, if you want to allow the change or not.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{0,5}");
TextFormatter<?> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    if (pattern.matcher(change.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
        // todo: remove error message/markup
        return change; // allow this change to happen
    } else {
        // todo: add error message/markup
        return null; // prevent change
    }
});
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression should be working fine, if we wish to validate a five-digits zip though, we might want to drop the `0` quantifier:

```
^[0-9]{5}$
^\d{5}$
```

For validation purposes, we might want to keep the start and end anchors, however for just testing, we can remove and see:

```
[0-9]{5}
\d{5}
```

It is likely that some other chars, would get through our inputs, which we do not wish to have.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DD5Xp7/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^[0-9]{5}$";
final String string = "01234\n"
     + "012345\n"
     + "0\n"
     + "1234";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the user enters at first only one number, than the second one and so on. But he isn't allowed to enter more than 5 digits. In your example it's fine, but in JavaFX every time the user enters one character the method check(String text) is called and of course when the user has entered only one digit it can't match this pattern [0-9]{5}